# Should perform query at the point of time for the event or the actual time when working with CQRS for queue system?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm trying to implement CQRS for a queue system where user can join a queue by clicking a button.  The system will tell the user if queue is full.

When the user click the button, it raised the command and triggered event like "user queued at 07:00 AM".  The handler for this event then (asynchronously) add a new participant to the queue.  It also updates the `full` flag of the queue depending on how many participants in the queue.  If the queue open for 1 hour, each participants get 5 minutes time slot, then it can hold 12 participants.

I would like to know which approach I should take when calculating the `full` flag:

1. Use `now()`: calculate the latest value, always query the latest state of the queue. If the command is "user queued at 07:00 AM" and now is "07:10 AM", the `full` flag reflects the condition at "07:10 AM".  Looks like will cause a problem when replaying the event.
2. Use `07:00 AM`: Calculate it based on the state at 07:00 AM. This means queries are more complicated: need to know how many participants at 07:00 AM.
3. Use `now()` when handling the event then raise another command to trigger event like "queue is full at 07:10".  This new "queue is full" event handler will eventually set the `full` flag instead of the current "user queued at 07:00 AM" event.  Is event raising another command valid for this use-case?
4. Having a long running process that check for `full` flag every minutes and raise the event like "queue is full at 07:10".  This looks nice since it decouples the "user queued" logic from "queue is full" logic.  But now, `full` flag is outdated if there are multiple users added to the queue in one minute.

Comment: What happens if the user clicks the button but the queue is already full?

Comment: The event handler will assign the user to wait-list if the queue is full.

Comment: why such a long lag between user placing request and processing in a first place? is this something users are leady to tolerate?

Comment: It is the restriction from infrastructure (message broker and serverless warmup delay).  Duplicate events may occur and there could be a delay as long as few minutes (although never as long as in my question description).  In CQRS architecture, shouldn't this be tolerable?